# Testing StateFlow that has emission in init block

Tags: android, kotlin, testing, turbine

I have BaseViewModel with logic that goes something like this:

```
val baseViewState = MutableViewState(State.Inital)

init {
  viewModelScope.launch {
    val data = getData()
    onDataGot()
    baseViewState.update {State.Second}
  }
}
```

and then in child:

```
val childViewState = MutableViewState(ChildState.Inital) 

override fun onDataGot() {
  childViewState.update { ChildState.Second}
}
```

Im am trying to test this like this:

```
val viewModel = ChildViewModel()

viewModel.childViewState.test 
   val firstItem = awaitItem() // is ChildState.Inital
   val secondItem = awaitItem() // is ChildState.Second

viewModel.baseViewState.test {
   val firstItem = awaitItem() // is be  State.Inital
   val secondItem = awaitItem() // will time out with: No value produced in 1s
}
```

Can somebody explan it to me why this would happend? should there also be more events on baseViewState since we are emiting in init ?

Comment: StateFlow can only hold one item at a time. It doesn’t replay its whole history for you when you start collecting it. The first item is whatever the current `value` is at the time you start collecting. But for that reason I would expect it to emit a single item State.Second, not State.Initial.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I understand this, but in this scenario, it looks like no emissions are coming to `baseViewState` in the test scope.

Comment: Since you're collecting it after the child already has been collected, the first item is already gone by the time you start collecting.

Comment: @Tenfour04 thats what I would expect yes, but item is still "State.Initial" so it did not have any updates yet.

Comment: What class is MutableViewState ?  I didn't notice before that doesn't say MutableStateFlow.